# Generating Coordinates of a N-sized diamond for Haskell

Tags: haskell, geometry, coordinates

So, I have to generate the coordinates to create a diamond on a grid.
I will receive the `center (x, y)` and the height `n` from center to top, then I need to generate the coordinates `[(x, y),..]` to print something like this (`n = 4` and `center = (4, 4)`):

```
        #
      # # #
    # # # # #
  # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # #
  # # # # # # #
    # # # # #
      # # #
        #
```

Where each # represents a position of the returned list. I don't have any clue about how to do this.

This is how I do it in kotlin:

```
fun diamond(n: Int, coord: Coord): List<Coord> {
  val coords = mutableSetOf<Coord>()
  for (i in 0..n) {
    for (j in 0..(n - i)) {
      coords.add(Coord((coord.x + i).absoluteValue, (coord.y + j).absoluteValue))
      coords.add(Coord((coord.x + i).absoluteValue, (coord.y - j).absoluteValue))
      coords.add(Coord((coord.x - i).absoluteValue, (coord.y + j).absoluteValue))
      coords.add(Coord((coord.x - i).absoluteValue, (coord.y - j).absoluteValue))
    }
  }
  return coords.toList()
}
```

P.S.: Printing is not a problem, I just need the coordinates.

Comment: Can you show what you tried, and what was not working?

Comment: I didn't tried anything in Haskell yet, I just have a Kotlin sample.

Comment: Haskell has list comprehensions, and it has pairs. Give it a try, and when you actually run into a problem come back and ask about that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make an analysis of the items in the coordinate. If the center is at `(x,y)`, then we know that there is one symbol exactly `n` places above the center, and `3` symbols exactly `n-1` above the center. etc.

We thus can use list comprehension here:

```
coordinates :: Integral i => i -> i -> i -> [(i,i)]
coordinates x y n = [(x+dx, y+dy) | dy <- [-n .. n], let ay = n - abs dy, dx <- [-ay .. ay]]
```